# Docker run entrypoint parameters disables published port

Tags: docker

This is working as expected:

```
docker run -it -p 1234:1234 --device=/dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv xxx/yyy
```

but when I provide entrypoint parameters `-a off -n on` then `-p 1234:1234` is no longer working

```
docker run -it -p 1234:1234 --device=/dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv xxx/yyy -a off -n on
```

How to provide entrypoint parameters without disabling `-p`?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your Dockerfile or `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` - but it is most likely that you are simply replacing the original parameters - which were responsible for running on a given port - with your own, so you also need to provide a port parameter in your override command.

Comment: You are right. Answer my question I will mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing entrypoint parameters in the `docker run` command will override any other parameter that may be defined in the original Dockerfile (usually in its `CMD`).

It is most likely that you are simply replacing the original parameters - which were responsible for running on a given port - with your own, so you also need to provide a port parameter in your list of override parameters.